# Haskell data type not recognised

Tags: haskell, types

I got this code:

```
data Station a b = Machine a b
             | Line [Station a b]
        deriving(Show)

data Machine a b = Req [(a,Int)] b
    deriving(Show)


machine :: [(a, Int)] -> b -> Station a b
machine l b = Req l b
```

and when i try to compile, it says that the signature of machine is wrong. It says it is [(a, Int)] -> b -> Machine a b, instead of [(a, Int)] -> b -> Station a b. But in my data type i say that Station a b = Machine a b. I don't get why this won't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two things called `Machine`. One is a type constructor that returns a `Station` type, and the other is a type. The two are unrelated, even though they share the same name.

It may be helpful to disambiguate the two terms by adding a `'` (prime) to the data constructor. In doing so, we can tie the `Machine'` data constructor to hold a `Machine` as its only argument:

```hs
data Station a b = Machine' (Machine a b)
             | Line [Station a b]
        deriving(Show)
```

And now we can update the `machine` function to use the newly defined constructor:

```hs
machine :: [(a, Int)] -> b -> Station a b
machine l b = Machine' (Req l b)
```

Comment: Ah, i see thanks! I mistakenly thought that the "Machine"s were the same. Thanks for clearing that up for me

Comment: @Midasso For future reference, it is `<!-- language-all: lang-hs -->` for Haskell.